# Синонимизировать скрейпинг

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две подозрительно похожие метки:

- [web-scraping](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) (132 вопроса)
- [веб-скрейпинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3) (35 вопросов)

Надо бы из синонимизировать (в пользу [веб-скрейпинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3)).

Comment: А по-моему, надо основной делать английскую, ну или переводить нормально.

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy а "переводить нормально" - это как? На [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3), например, именно так как сейчас русскоязычная метка.

Comment: "Скрапинг" - я думаю ещё хуже, чем "скрейпинг".

Comment: [анализ-html] может быть? Это не совсем перевод, но технически скрейпинг ничем не отличается от "легального" анализа HTML.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, у меня анализ больше с парсингом ассоциируется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метки описывают одно и то же, поэтому их действительно нужно синонимизировать. Что я и сделал. Поменять название, если уж очень хочется и без этого никак не обойтись можно и потом.

Синонимизировал в сторону русскоязычной в текущем варианте оно как раз так упоминается на [Вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3).